# Splitting up an array in python into sub arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array which is 1 -> 160. I want to split this into 10 arrays that are split every sixteen numbers. This is what I have so far:

```
amplitude=[]
for i in range (0,160):
    amplitude.append(i+1)

print(amplitude)


#split arrays up into a line for each sample
traceno=10                  #number of traces in file
samplesno=16               #number of samples in each trace. This wont change.

amplitude_split=np.zeros((traceno,samplesno) ,dtype=np.int) 


#fill in the arrays with amplitude/sample numbers
for i in range(len(amplitude)):             
    for j in range(traceno):                
        for k in range(samplesno):          
            amplitude_split[j,k]=amplitude[i]  

print(amplitude_split[1,:])
```

As an output I only get `[160 160 160 160 160 160 160 160 160 160 160 160 160 160 160 160]`
Where I require something along the lines of:

`[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16]`

`[17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32]`
etc...

Comment: [how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Comment: oops I copied the wrong bit over... it should say amplitude[]

Comment: maybe use: `np.array_split(range(1,161), 10))` (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16935535/9758194))

Comment: @PatrickArtner for vanilla Python, yes, but this appears to be a Numpy question.

Comment: @Karl Thats why I did not dupe hammer - the only hint that this is numpy is the usage of np.zero in the code. chunking 160 elements and a dependency on numpy is only ok if you use numpy already imho - edited the tags to emphasize numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if we're using Numpy arrays, we can use Numpy functionality:

```
amplitude = np.arange(1, 161)
amplitude_split = amplitude.reshape(10, 16)
```

Otherwise, you've already been linked to [how to do it for plain lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks), but I'd like to point out that you *still* don't need a loop to fill `amplitude` in the first place:

```
amplitude = list(range(1, 161))
```

In general, with Python you should be trying hard *not* to think in terms of starting with an initially blank "storage" area that you then fill in. Just create the data you want directly - by conversions of the sort above, by list comprehensions etc., or if necessary by `.append()` ing - rather than overwriting a dummy value.

Comment: Thanks, this has worked! I know about the filling in a list, I was just writing a test for a different piece of code I was writing which was too long to run each time (an array of 16000000 numbers)

Answer (score 2):

You are nesting the loops. So you consistently fill the new array with the same number from the first one, and end with the last one `160` repeated everywhere.

You only need to copy the list into a 1D numpy array, and then reshape it:

```
amplitude_split=np.array(amplitude, dtype=np.int).reshape((traceno,samplesno))
```

Answer (score 0):

See grouper in https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```